# Android duplicate items on listview

Tags: android, listview, duplicates

I'm using a listview to load all database items inside it, and it works. The problem is everytime i recall that activity my listview is populated my duplicate items.
Here the code:

```
public class UserActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();
private ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_activity);

    DataHandler db = new DataHandler(this);
    List<Data> items = db.getTitle();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofName);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

e.g. if i insert item "Facebook" it will be inserted inside my database, when i call UserActivity it will load database content(in this case Facebook item) and show all its content inside my listView. The problem is when i do this my listView show me 2 Facebook item. If i have 2 items, when i recall UserActivity it will show me 4 items.

What's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with

```
 public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It should not be static else this will be crated once and it will not initialize on the next activity recreate.Remove the static keyword and write like this-

```
 public ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();
```

OR
Ensure the ArrayList is having no elements when you satrts populating from the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1.) Remove the `static` keyword from

```
public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you can't remove the keyword for any reason, use solution 2.).

2.) Call the method `clear()` of your `ArrayList` before adding new entries.

Comment: i have to follow 2) solution because i need to declare ArrayList static. I call clear() method before adding new entries but when i add item my listView shows me only the last inserted because calling clear it clear all list